# scangearmp2 cannot detect scanners

Tags: scanner, canon

I have a Canon TS9100 series printer which is accessible via WiFi.
I sucessully installed this printer as a network
printer by going to
System -> Control Centre -> Printers -> Add
and follwing instructions.
I can print to this printer without problem.
But when I try to scan a document using scangearmp2 I get told that it cannot detect any scanners.
OTOH if I go to Applications -> Graphics ->
Document Scanner, I am told "Ready to Scan" (the
scanner being "ESCL Canon TS9100 series", which seems to be as it should be).

However I prefer the "feel" of scangearmp2 (when it works!) and would like to get it going.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 with a Mate 1.24.0 desktop.

I have read the "similar questions" and their answer, but this did not get me anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> However I prefer the "feel" of scangearmp2 (when it works!) and would like to get it going.

Then you need to contact Canon and get them to sort it out for you. Good luck with that! Let us know how it goes.

This software is not provided by Ubuntu. Ubuntu cannot do anything if it does not work for you. sane-escl and sane-airscan are the relevant SANE backends to use with your TS910.